# How do I use Basic Auth and Bearer Token Auth with python requests module?

Tags: python, python-requests, basic-authentication, bearer-token

## Question

How do I use Basic Auth and Bearer Token Auth with python requests module?

## Background

I write curl script as same as I want to do with python requests module.

```bash
curl --location --request POST 'https://username@password:example.com/path/to/endpoint' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer SOME_TOKEN' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
    "example": "example"
}'
```

Below code is python edition for the above script.

```py
import requests
import json

url = "https://username@password:example.com/path/to/endpoint"

payload = json.dumps({
  "example": "example"
})
headers = {
  'Authorization': 'Bearer SOME_TOKEN',
  'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}

response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload)
```

But this Python code does not work as intended.
I captured http request that this python code sends.
The result is below.

```
POST /path/to/endpoint HTTP/1.1
Host: example
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Authorization: Basic xxxxx
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 31
Content-Type: application/json
User-Agent: python-requests/2.28.1

{"example": "example"}
```

I don't know why `Auhorization: Basic xxxx` appears.
I intend that `Authorization: Bearer SOME_TOKEN`.

Please teach me how to use Basic auth and Bearer token auth with python requests module.

## appendix

I think that I can't use both Basic auth and Bearer token auth with python requests module.
Because this module depends on python http.client module, and I think this module does not support basic auth with including username and password in url(https://username:password@example.com/ format).

I examined the http request that the above codes sends to http server.

Comment: If you are using a Bearer token, why are you putting your authentication into the URL?  You should be able to just... remove it?

Comment: Thank you for your comments. Because this api is deployed in staging environment. We restrict anyone from accessing our stagin environment with Basic auth. Bearer token auth is as same as production one.

Comment: Yes, so why are you providing basic authentication at all?  Bearer tokens normally replace basic authentication entirely, so your URL should not have a username:password in it. Have you tried just removing them?

Comment: I think so too. But this api is not developed by us. Other team develops this api. So I can't change this authentication method.

Comment: So is it expecting both headers?  Can you just try without the Basic auth in the URL?  Like for your python script, literally just put https://example.com/path/to/endpoint.  Then the Bearer should work.

Comment: I dont't know why this authentication is adopted. I hear that this system is very legacy. So this authentication may be remnant.

Comment: No. It isn't expected both headers. This system expected that http request includes Basic auth in URL and Bearer Token in Headers. Of course, if I remove basic auth, Bearer token works well. But the system denied requests because of invalid basic auth.

Comment: The Basic auth in URL is only used to construct the Authorization: Basic header.  It is not provided in the GET/POST request or any server side visible URL.  So either it IS expecting both Headers, or you're mistaken somewhere else.
So, you can make your code manually construct either Basic or Bearer URL depending on what's available.  Basic is just a base64 encoding of the username and password so it's easy to replicate.

Comment: I don't know `https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Authentication#access_using_credentials_in_the_url`. I read this [document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Authentication#access_using_credentials_in_the_url). This document said that this method is deprecated. But this method seems to allows me to use both authentication. For now, I understand that I can't use both auth with this module. Thank you.